# Jenkins/Maven nullpointer using custom profile

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, webdriver, imagemagick

got a very strange error occurring - it seems when I try and set a custom firefox profile ( I need to disable the geolocate feature) and try to run tests in Jenkins I get null pointers.  Using Eclipse and maven from the command line, I have no issues.  The tests run with no failures due to this.

The code I am using is:

```
myprofile.setPreference("geo.enabled", false);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
```

The error (that led me to believe it's this) was:

```
googleHomePage(my.seleniumConfiguration.tests.GoogleDefaultTest)  Time elapsed: 0.49 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at my.company.steps.WebDriverSteps.<init>(WebDriverSteps.java:77)
    at my.seleniumConfiguration.tests.GoogleDefaultTest.setUp(GoogleDefaultTest.java:54)
```

Anyone had this before or have any ideas what I have done wrong?

Comment: The only way I work with FF profiles is to indicate profile filesystem location in the FirefoxProfile contructor, instead of setting it programatically. Does it work for you this way?

I can't answer your question, there is not enough code/stack trace presented here.

Comment: Ok so I've had a bit more of a chance to look at this.  With a simple case:.  <br/>    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();    
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(); <br/> works exactly as expected.  However, if I change this to <br/>    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();    
    FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("Automation");
    myprofile.setPreference("geo.enabled", false);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile); <br/> then things go wrong.

Comment: Had a simple case which didn't use the named profile:
`FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
driver = new FirefoxDriver();`
This works as expected.  No errors are thrown.  Changing to this:
`ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();`
`FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("Automation");`
`myprofile.setPreference("geo.enabled", false);`
   driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);    
Gives the null pointers.

Comment: Apologies for the double post - the post didn't appear here, so thought it hadn't saved.

Comment: In terms of errors: `googleHomePage(my.company.tests.GoogleDefaultTest)  Time elapsed: 0.421 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at my.company.steps.WebDriverSteps.<init>(WebDriverSteps.java:41)
 at my.company.tests.GoogleDefaultTest.setUp(GoogleDefaultTest.java:50)`  line 50 of GoogleDefaultTest.java is `steps = new WebDriverSteps();` which is where I define actions in my test.

Comment: @automatictester  - how would you set the location? I'd be interested to see your approach?

Comment: Have traced the issue to one line `myprofile.setPreference("geo.enabled", false);` problem is, I can't see why this line would fail with Jenkins (it works with no issues via command line and also via eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I got this figured out - I hate NullPointers as isn't a lot to go on.

Anyway, another topic (I can't find the link) basically said that when Firefox was launched from Jenkins it was using a user directory tied to Jenkins.  So, I changed my code and created a user profile in a different location - pointed to that and, no error.